# simple 2-column layout

Tags: html, css, css-float

At the bottom of [this page](http://festivals.ie/festival/show/1/electric-picnic-2012), there are two columns. The right-hand column contains a twitter feed and the left-hand column shows a YouTube video and a comments section. The columns are created by the following HTML & CSS

```
.leftCol {
    margin-right: 365px;
}

.rightCol {
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 355px;
}

<div class="rightCol">
<div>

<div class="leftCol">
<div>
```

But for reasons I don't understand, the left-hand column doesn't slide up into the vacant space to the left of the the right-hand column.

Comment: Well it isn't the cols themselves... your css works perfectly well in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t8tAk/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just remove `clear: both;` from your inline styling of `<h2 class="banner bgImage video">`.

Comment: This is exactly the problem.  Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `.leftCol` styling to:

```
.leftCol {
    float: left;
    width: 365px;
}
```

The margin is creating an illusion of space to the right of the left column.